# Проблема при загрузке картинки в группу через API VK

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Добрый день, подскажите в чём ошибка, пытаюсь загрузить картинку через api

делаю так:

```
$images = "http://test.loc/image.png"; // картинка на изображение

// формирую ссылку на загрузку

$serverUrlVK = $this->getWallUploadServer($group_id,$vkparams->vktoken);

//Загружаю на сервер
$imageVkData = $this->uploadImage($serverUrlVK,$images);

var_dump($imageVkData);

//{ ["server"]=> int(317529) ["photo"]=> string(2) "[]" ["hash"]=> string(32) "648447678d67fc4caf531e6a67d79b36" }
```

Почему `["photo"]` пустая?

п.с. путь к картинке указывал и абсолютный...

функции задействованные выше:

```
 private function getWallUploadServer($gid,$vktoken){
     $request = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getWallUploadServer";
     $params = array (
            'access_token'  => $vktoken,
            'gid'=> $gid
             );
     $result = json_decode($this->callMethod($request, $params));
     $upload_url = $result->response->upload_url;
     return $upload_url;
 }

 private function uploadImage($uploadUrl,$image){
     $params = array(
             "photo" => "@" . $image
             );
     $result = json_decode($this->callMethod($uploadUrl, $params));
     return $result;
 }

 private function callMethod($request, $params)        {
     $c=curl_init();
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
     $result = curl_exec($c);
     if($result === false)    {
         $result = curl_error($c);
     }
     curl_close($c);
     return $result;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $params = array(
      "photo" => "@" .$SERVER['document_root']. "/img/image.jpg"
      );
```